# Udf - Implement custom less than function in bq via UDF

Tags: google-bigquery

when trying to run the following SQL in big query:

```sql
CREATE TEMP FUNCTION
  lt_(x ANY TYPE,
    y ANY TYPE)
  RETURNS BOOL AS (
    CASE
      WHEN bqutil.fn.typeof(x) = 'DATETIME' AND bqutil.fn.typeof(y) = 'TIMESTAMP' THEN (CAST(x AS timestamp) > y)
      WHEN bqutil.fn.typeof(x) = 'TIMESTAMP' AND bqutil.fn.typeof(y) = 'DATETIME' THEN (x > CAST(y AS timestamp))
    ELSE
    x > y
  END
    );
SELECT
  lt_(dt,ts) AS test,
  *
FROM (
  SELECT
    CURRENT_DATETIME() AS dt,
    CURRENT_TIMESTAMP() AS ts) base_
```

I get an error:

`Invalid function lt_ No matching signature for operator > for argument types: DATETIME, TIMESTAMP. Supported signature: ANY > ANY Analysis of function Templated_SQL_Function:lt_ failed at [13:3]`

can someone explain me what's the problem and how can use the udf created at the beginning of the query?

Thanks in advance!